# How to write Gradle build currentVersion to a file

Tags: jenkins, gradle, version

I am trying to do following steps:

I have a `build.gradle` file configured for my project.   I want to execute the currentVersion task for my project to get the current version that the build generated and then save it to a text file.   I wil
l run this build using jenkins and use that text file to get the version number to download the correct artifact from Nexus Repository.

I feel either of the below ways can help me achieve this:

1. Is there a way to run only the currentVersion task for my project through Jenkins and store the result in a text file ?
2. Is there a way to run the currentVersion task through my build script and write the output to a text file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make use of task input/output caching you could do something like the following in your `build.gradle`:

```groovy
tasks.create('currentVersion') {
  outputs.file('versionFile.txt')
  inputs.property('version', project.version)

  doLast {
    project.file('versionFile.txt') << project.version
  }
}
```

Then, you can run the task like `./gradlew currentVersion` and the output will go to the file that you want to write to. Next time you run the task, the file will only be updated if the inputs or outputs change.

Comment: This works fine, but note it assumes a clean environment with no `versionFile.txt`. TBF, this would usually be the case on a CI server, which was the context of the original post. Elsewhere, this will keep appending to the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, I added Execute Shell. Within execute shell, I can run gradle tasks like this.

```
./gradlew currentVersion > bbc.txt
```

This way I got the task output in a file.

Comment: This is an alternate option if you do not want to modify build.gradle file.